# How to add a use UserControl containing List in Windows 8.1 App?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I want add a list in UserControl and its values are coming from Json. So how can I bind those values into UserControl from another page and also I want to add a SelectionChanged Event for it.

The scenario is as below:

I have a xaml page containing an image plugin(image). On clicking on Image I want to open UserControl containing list values( for e.g. Take Photo, Select from Library,Record Video and Cancel). Once the user selects the item based on that different method are called.

I was achieving the same approach using CustomMessageBox in Windows Phone 8 but that is not available and I may need to use UserControl to achieve this.

Please guide me for this.

**Update**

What I have tried so far.

UserControl.Xaml

```
<UserControl
x:Class="TestApp.Resources.CameraPluginOptions"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyCouncilServices.Resources"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="CameraPlugin" 
     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GenericListViewContainerStyle}"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EvidenceListItemTemplate}"
     ItemSource="{Binding ItemSource}"
             />
</Grid>
```

UserControl.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class CameraPluginOptions : UserControl
{


    public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;

    public List<SUBPARAM> ItemSource
    {
        get { return (List<SUBPARAM>)GetValue(evidenceItemSourceproperty); }
        set { SetValue(evidenceItemSourceproperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty evidenceItemSourceproperty =
                    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(List<SUBPARAM>),
                                                    typeof(CameraPluginOptions), new PropertyMetadata(0));


    public SUBPARAM SelectedOption
    {
        get { return (SUBPARAM)GetValue(selectedoptionproperty);}
        set { SetValue(selectedoptionproperty,value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty selectedoptionproperty =
                    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedOption", typeof(SUBPARAM),
                                                    typeof(CameraPluginOptions), new PropertyMetadata(0));


    private void PluginSelectionChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(SelectionChanged !=null)
            SelectionChanged(this,new EventArgs());
    }
    public CameraPluginOptions()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The Page from which I want to use UserControl

TestUserControlPage.xaml.cs

```
PluginControl.DataContext = new EvidenceSource(){ItemSource=MCSManager.Instance.currentClientParams.EVIDENCE_MENU.SUB_PARAMS};
PluginControl.SelectionChanged += MediaListSelectionChanged;
```

TestUSerControl.xaml where I am using UserControl

```
<Grid x:Name="imagePlugin"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          Height="400"
          Width="600"
          Visibility="Collapsed"
          xmlns:local="using:TestApp.Resources">
        <local:CameraPluginOptions x:Name="PluginControl"
                                   />
```

What I actually want to do is bind the list which I get from Json into UserControl ListBox.Itemsource and then I want to have SelectionChanged Event on same page from which UserControl is called. When a user selects an Item particular action should take place.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood correctly - have you tried setting *DataContext* of your *UserControl*? Can you show some code which may help to understand?

Comment: @Romasz I am not much aware of UserControl in details. Can you explain with some sample code.

Comment: Like I've said - I'm not sure what you have on your mind. Can you share some code?

Comment: @Romasz Please check. I have updated my question and explained what I actually want to do.

Comment: Ok, you are setting the *DataContext*, but where do you set ListBox item source? Is there an binding to which DataContext is needed?

Comment: @Romasz Can you suggest where I should add Item source property and how it will bind in UserControl if I assign it in different page.

Comment: I see that you know *DependencyProperty*, so defining DP for *ItemsSoruce* may be one solution, you can also think of doing it in code somehow. Everything depends on your needs and expectations.

Comment: @Romasz I am getting values when debugging in UserControl ItemSource but the UserControl is not displaying. I have placed it in a Grid where I want to use it and set visibility to collapsed in start, but when I change its visibility to Visible its not displaying. Can you suggest what can be the issue?